# Split RDD into RDD's with no repeating values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD of Pairs as below :

```
(105,918)
(105,757)
(502,516)
(105,137)
(516,816)
(350,502)
```

I would like to split it into two RDD's such that the first has only the pairs with non-repeating values (for both key and value) and the second will have the rest of the omitted pairs.

So from the above we could get two RDD's

```
 1) (105,918)
    (502,516)

 2) (105,757) - Omitted as 105 is already included in 1st RDD
    (105,137) - Omitted as 105 is already included in 1st RDD
    (516,816) - Omitted as 516 is already included in 1st RDD
    (350,502) - Omitted as 502 is already included in 1st RDD
```

Currently I am using a mutable Set variable to track the elements already selected after coalescing the original RDD to a single partition :

```
val evalCombinations = collection.mutable.Set.empty[String]
val currentValidCombinations = allCombinations
  .filter(p => {
  if(!evalCombinations.contains(p._1) && !evalCombinations.contains(p._2)) {
    evalCombinations += p._1;evalCombinations += p._2; true
  } else
    false
})
```

This approach is limited by memory of the executor on which the operations run. Is there a better scalable solution for this ?

Comment: I'm confused with the question description vs the example: The description says 'split it into two RDD's such that the first has only the pairs with non-repeating values (for both key and value)'. Yet, the example shows that the resulting RDD contains 105, which repeats 3 times in the sample, 502 - 2 time, 516 - 2 times. In fact, following the description, the resulting RDD in your example should be empty. Care to clarify?

Comment: @maasg In my reading, it means that the RDD is required to be split into two parts. First RDD should consist of unique key and values. Any repeating key/value would go into the second RDD. So in this example first RDD has ((105, 918), (502, 516)). within this set of key values, there is no repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version, which will require more memory for driver.

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark._

def getUniq(rdd: RDD[(Int, Int)], sc: SparkContext): RDD[(Int, Int)] = {

    val keys   = rdd.keys.distinct
    val values = rdd.values.distinct

    // these are the keys which appear in value part also.
    val both = keys.intersection(values) 

    val bBoth = sc.broadcast(both.collect.toSet)

    // remove those key-value pairs which have value which is also a key.
    val uKeys = rdd.filter(x => !bBoth.value.contains(x._2))
               .reduceByKey{ case (v1, v2) => v1 }  // keep uniq keys

    uKeys.map{ case (k, v) => (v, k) }              // swap key, value
         .reduceByKey{ case (v1, v2) => v1 }        // keep uniq value
         .map{ case (k, v) => (v, k) }              // correct placement

}

def getPartitionedRDDs(rdd: RDD[(Int, Int)], sc: SparkContext) = {

    val r = getUniq(rdd, sc)    
    val remaining = rdd subtract r
    val set = r.flatMap { case (k, v) => Array(k, v) }.collect.toSet
    val a = remaining.filter{ case (x, y) => !set.contains(x) && 
                                             !set.contains(y) }
    val b = getUniq(a, sc)
    val part1 = r union b
    val part2 = rdd subtract part1
   (part1, part2)
}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array((105,918),(105,757),(502,516),
                               (105,137),(516,816),(350,502)))

val (first, second) = getPartitionedRDDs(rdd, sc)
// first.collect:  ((516,816), (105,918), (350,502))
// second.collect: ((105,137), (502,516), (105,757))

val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array((839,841),(842,843),(840,843),
                                (839,840),(1,2),(1,3),(4,3)))

val (f, s) = getPartitionedRDDs(rdd1, sc)
//f.collect: ((839,841), (1,2), (840,843), (4,3))
```

Comment: Thanks Shyamendra. I was able to test this out today . Definitely using the driver memory seems to be a better approach than executor memory in this case.   Unfortunately, It does not seem to work with the following data though : `val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array((839,841),(842,843),(840,843),(839,840)))`

Comment: Yes, it didn't check for repeating values, have updated the answer.